# Passing an Array of Objects into a Function

Tags: c++, arrays, function, class, object

I have a class that defines object.name as "Ben" and object.favNum as 25.

I also have an array (names) to store 5 objects of this class.

Before I output the attributes of the objects in the array, I change the value of names[0].name to "Jim" and names[0].favNum to 40, using pointer notation.

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>

class Person {
public:
    std::string name = "Ben";
    int favNum = 25;
};


int main()
{
    Person names[5];

    Person *ptr = &names[0];


    // Changing Values
    (ptr + 0)->name = "Jim";
    (ptr + 0)->favNum = 40;


    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
    {
        std::cout << (std::string) (ptr + i)->name   << std::endl;
        std::cout << (int) (ptr + i)->favNum << std::endl << std::endl;
    }

    system("pause>0");
}
```

Output:

```
Jim
40

Ben
25

Ben
25

Ben
25

Ben
25
```

Where I have the "Changing Values" comment, I want to replace those 2 lines with a function.
The function will be able to change the values as I am doing with the 2 lines.
This is where I am having a problem.

I'm struggling with figuring out what type to declare the function as, how to pass the pointer in, how to receive the pointer, and how to change  the values of the objects in the array in the function.

Comment: Any reasoning why you're using raw arrays and raw pointers in c++ code? You'll be much better and easier off with a `std::array<Person,5>` or even a `std::vector<person>`.

Comment: You don't need to cast things to the type they already have. Sprinkling cast over code is a reliable way to introduce bugs that are hard to find.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Sorry, I don't know what the alternative is. I am pretty new to C++ and only started using arrays and pointers yesterday. This is how I've been shown to do it. I take it there's a better way?

Comment: Please also don't write `(thing + 0)`. That's just `thing`. All these odd tics just clutter the code and make it a lot harder to read for no reason.

Comment: Also, `(ptr + i)->name` is usually written `ptr[i].name`.

Comment: @Ben There's pretty good documentation material: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container _"started using arrays and pointers yesterday."_ That's definitely the worst starting point you can use if you want to learn how to code in c++.

Comment: Here you can avoid pointers. For example, just use `names[0] = {"Jim", 40};`

Comment: I might even recommend not to bother learning about pointers, until you have some actual need to. There are far less legitimate use cases for pointers in C++ than in C because references and the standard library exist in C++. Sadly though, many teaching materials still think that to learn C++, one should first start with C. That's not a great idea. And yeah, because C++ 'raw' arrays retain all the oddities of C ones, `std::array` is preferable as it is a regular object and therefore acts like all the other ones do.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend against the use of pointers, unless you really need pointers.

```cpp
// use references instead
void change(Person &person) {
    person.name = "Jim";
    person.favNum = 40;
};

int main()
{
    Person names[5];

    change(names[0]);

    // ...
}
```

The appropriate way to write such a function would be using references. A reference is similar to a pointer, but can never be `nullptr`. In your case you don't need nullability, you just need to edit a `Person` without copying it.

You probably want `change()` to be parametric though:

```cpp
// use references instead
void change(Person &person, std::string name, int favNum) {
    person.name = std::move(name);
    person.favNum = favNum;
}
```

But now you are assigning all members of `Person` using this function, which makes it pointless. It would be simpler if you assigned `Person`. Why not use a `struct` and aggregate initialization:

```cpp
struct Person {
    std::string name = "Ben";
    int favNum = 25;
};

int main()
{
    Person names[5];

    names[0] = {"Jim", 40};

    // ...
}
```

---

On a side note, what you are doing here is unnecessary complicated:

```cpp
(ptr + 0)->name = "Jim";

// this is equivalent to
ptr[0].name = "Jim";

// this is equivalent to
ptr->name = "Jim";
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how your code should look in *"real"* c++ (the setting of the values will be done in the constructor function or using the `setNameAndFavNum()` function):

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

struct Person {
public:
    Person(const std::string& name_ = "Ben", int favNum_ = 25) : name(name_), favNum(favNum_) {};
    void setNameAndFavNum(const std::string& name_, int favNum_) {
        name = name_;
        favNum = favNum_;
    };

    std::string name;
    int favNum;
};    

int main() {
    std::array<Person, 5> names;


    // Changing Values
    names[0].setNameAndFavNum("Jim", 40);

    // Alternatively you can use the constructor and implicit copy constructor
    // names[0] = {"Jim", 40};

    for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++)  {
        std::cout << names[i].name << std::endl;
        std::cout << names[i].favNum << std::endl << std::endl;
    }
}
```

You shouldn't mess around with pointers and raw values when writing c++ code.

Comment: @Jan Is that better?

Comment: Yes, it is better, but there is still no necessity for `setNameAndFavNum` and the constructor. Both could be replaced with aggregate initialization and assignment, which are defined by default.

Comment: @JanSchultke I added `setNameAndFavNum ()` to demonstrate use of a function, which is what the OP originally asked for.

Comment: Technically `operator=` is a function too :) I understand what you mean, but OP's motivation behind extracting those lines into a function seemed to be making the code more concise. Judging by OP's use of pointers they are not the most experienced C++ developer. In such cases, recommending a simpler and more canonical way will help them more than giving them exactly what they asked for. If nobody ever tells you to use references, you might keep misusing pointers forever.